# Por que quando eu uso a tabulação em um printf, tem casos em que ele não tabula corretamente?

Tags: c, printf

Tenho este código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int fahr, celsius;
    int inicio, fim, incr;

    inicio = 0;
    fim = 300;
    incr = 20;
    fahr = inicio;
    while(fahr <= fim){
        celsius = 5 * (fahr-32)/9;
        printf("Fahr: %d\tCelsius:%d\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + incr;
    }
}
```

A saida está sendo:

```
Fahr: 0 Celsius: -17
Fahr: 20    Celsius: -6
Fahr: 40    Celsius: 4
Fahr: 60    Celsius: 15
Fahr: 80    Celsius: 26
Fahr: 100   Celsius: 37
Fahr: 120   Celsius: 48
Fahr: 140   Celsius: 60
Fahr: 160   Celsius: 71
Fahr: 180   Celsius: 82
Fahr: 200   Celsius: 93
Fahr: 220   Celsius: 104
Fahr: 240   Celsius: 115
Fahr: 260   Celsius: 126
Fahr: 280   Celsius: 137
Fahr: 300   Celsius: 148
```

Por que na primeira linha ele não faz a tabulação mas nas outras sim?

Comment: A tabulação é feita em colunas de quatro caracteres cada, então na primeira como `fahr` possui valor de único caractere `0`, a palavra `Celsius` é deslocada para terceira coluna de tabulação e nos outros casos é deslocada para quarta coluna.  Formate o valor com no mínimo dois caracteres de extensão com preenchimento de zero `printf("Fahr: %02d\tCelsius:%d\n", fahr, celsius);`

Comment: Outra opção: `printf("Fahr: %-2d\tCelsius: %d\n", fahr, celsius)`. O `-` indica para alinhar à esquerda, e o `2` é o tamanho mínimo. Ou simplesmente defina um tamanho maior e remova o TAB: `printf("Fahr: %-10dCelsius: %d\n", fahr, celsius);`

Answer (score 3):

Quando é encontrado um `\t`, ele avança até o próximo *tab stop*. E isso varia conforme o tamanho que estiver configurado no terminal que você está usando.

Por exemplo, no meu terminal o tamanho *tab stop* é 8, então a saída ficou assim:

```
Fahr: 0 Celsius:-17
Fahr: 20        Celsius:-6
Fahr: 40        Celsius:4
etc...
```

O que acontece é que sempre que há um `\t`, ele avança para o próximo *tab stop*, que no meu caso é a cada 8 caracteres. Seria algo assim (a "régua" abaixo foi <strike>descaradamente copiada</strike> inspirada [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13094746)):

```
0       8      16      24
|.......|.......|.......|...
Fahr: 0 Celsius:-17
Fahr: 20        Celsius:-6
```

No caso, o `0`, `8`, `16`, etc são os *tab stops* (sempre múltiplos de 8, já que o tamanho no meu terminal é 8).

Então no primeiro caso, o zero ocupa a posição 6, e o `\t` fica na posição 7. Então ele avança até o próximo *tab stop*, que é a posição 8.
Já no segundo caso, o `\t` está na posição 8, então ele avança até o próximo *tab stop*, que é a posição 16.

---

No seu caso (assumindo que os espaços mostrados estão desta forma mesmo), parece que o tamanho *tab stop* é 4, então ficaria assim:

```
0   4   8  12  16  20  24
|...|...|...|...|...|...|...
Fahr: 0 Celsius: -17
Fahr: 20    Celsius: -6
```

Agora os *tab stops* são as posições múltiplas de 4.

No primeiro caso, o zero ocupa a posição 6, e o `\t` fica na posição 7. Então ele avança até o próximo *tab stop*, que é a posição 8.
E no segundo caso, o `\t` está na posição 8, então ele avança até o próximo *tab stop*, que é a posição 12.

---

Uma solução seria, em vez de depender do *tab stop*, simplesmente definir um tamanho fixo para os números. Por exemplo, se trocar para:

```c
printf("Fahr: %-6d Celsius: %d\n", fahr, celsius);
```

No caso, o `-` diz para alinhar à esquerda, e o `6` indica o tamanho a ser usado (e preenchido com espaços, ou seja, tanto faz o tamanho do *tab stop*, sempre usará este tamanho). Com isso a saída será:

```
Fahr: 0      Celsius: -17
Fahr: 20     Celsius: -6
Fahr: 40     Celsius: 4
Fahr: 60     Celsius: 15
Fahr: 80     Celsius: 26
Fahr: 100    Celsius: 37
Fahr: 120    Celsius: 48
Fahr: 140    Celsius: 60
Fahr: 160    Celsius: 71
Fahr: 180    Celsius: 82
Fahr: 200    Celsius: 93
Fahr: 220    Celsius: 104
Fahr: 240    Celsius: 115
Fahr: 260    Celsius: 126
Fahr: 280    Celsius: 137
Fahr: 300    Celsius: 148
```

Mas claro que os tamanhos exatos vai depender do que você precisa. Por exemplo, se algum número tiver mais que 6 dígitos, ficará desalinhado novamente:

```
Fahr: 999999 Celsius: 555537
Fahr: 1000019 Celsius: 555548
```

Mas aí você tem que adaptar a saída para cada caso. De qualquer forma, a ideia geral e a explicação estão aí. Você pode ver na [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) todas as opções disponíveis aceitas por `printf`.